# Swift: initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Decimal' conform to 'BinaryInteger'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a function that calculates and returns compound interest. The variables are having different data types. Whenever I run the program I get an error `initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Decimal' conform to 'BinaryInteger'`. The following is my code:

```swift
import Foundation

class Compound{
    var p:Double
    var t:Int
    var r:Double 
    var n:Int 
    var interest:Double
    var amount:Double 
    init(p:Double,t:Int,r:Double,n:Int){
        self.p = p
        self.t = t
        self.r = r
        self.n = n        
    }

    func calculateAmount() -> Double { 
        amount = p * Double(pow(Decimal(1 + (r / Double(n))),n * t))
        return amount
    }

}
```

The Error:

```
error: initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Decimal' conform to 'BinaryInteger'
        amount = p * Double(pow(Decimal(1 + (r / Double(n))),n * t))
                     ^
```

After looking at a similar problem I've also tried the following technique but I'm still getting the same error

```swift
func calculateAmount() -> Double { 
        let gg:Int = n * t
        amount = p * Double(pow(Decimal(1 + (r / Double(n))),Int(truncating: gg as NSNumber)  ))
        return amount
    }
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Why use Decimal and not Int?

Comment: If I use Int instead of Decimal in pow() it gives this error: `error: cannot convert the value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Decimal'`. Also according to Apple documentation `func pow(_ x: Decimal, _ y: Int) -> Decimal`

Comment: Not sure if this would work, but if you cast pow to an NSNumber - `amount = p * Double(truncating: pow(Decimal(1 + (r / Double(n))),n * t) as NSNumber)`.

Comment: Nobody can read that. Break it up. At least put it on more lines! Maybe don’t use letters, unless that’s some kind of of domain standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to use the Double `func pow(_: Double, _: Double) -> Double` instead of using Decimal `func pow(_ x: Decimal, _ y: Int) -> Decimal` considering that you want to return a Double:

```
@discardableResult
func calculateAmount() -> Double {
    amount = p * pow(1 + (r / Double(n)), Double(n) * Double(t))
    return amount
}
```